# How does javascript create one-way data binding with DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom, ecmascript-6

I don't know if "one-way data binding" is actually the correct definition, but I have a class called `timesheetRow`, which represents a row in a table when called.

The class has a method called `generateRow()`, which binds `<td>` elements to the object properties and then appends all of them to a parent `<tr>` element. I do it this way because before returning the row, I gotta add some event listeners for validation purposes. The code is like this:

```
class timesheetRow{

    generateRow(){

        this.row = htmlToElement(`
            <tr>
            </tr>
        `);

        this.nodes.workHours = htmlToElement(`
            <td>
                <input name="workHours" 
                min=0 
                max=24 
                class="form-control workHours" 
                type="number">
            </td>
        `);

        this.nodes.workProject = htmlToElement(`
            <td>
                <select name="workProject" 
                class="form-control workProject" 
                required>
                    <option disabled selected value="">Sin proyecto asignado</option>
                    <option value="1">Proyecto 1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        `);

        this.nodes.workHours.addEventListener("input", event => {
            this.row.querySelector('.workProject').disabled = parseInt(event.target.value) < 1;
        });

        for (let node in this.nodes) {
            this.row.appendChild(this.nodes[node]);
        }

        return this.row;
    }
}
```

This is a very abridged version of the actual code, but I hope it will work to clarify my question.

If you take a look at the event listener I added to the workHours element, it works directly on the row stored as one of my object properties, but changing that property automatically changes the DOM as well. So, as far as I know, that looks like one-way data binding. When the workHours value is below 1, the workProject select element gets disabled. I'm not directly changing the DOM, I'm changing my object.

I would like to know what's going on behind the scenes here. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to answer my question!

Comment: What's `htmlToElement`?

Comment: A helper function I created to convert a string to an element using templates. @SergiuParaschiv

Comment: There is no binding going on here, it's just your storing a reference to the Dom nodes,..

Answer (score 1):

`this.row.querySelector('.workProject')` returns a reference to a DOM Node, which is an object representing a DOM Node.

`disabled` is a property on a `select` Node which manipulates the way the browser renders it. The rendering engine itself knows it needs to redraw the input when you change that `disabled` property.

There is no magic involved.

1. you type something in the input, an `input` event is dispatched
2. you added an `input` listener on the `input`, so the listener gets called every time (1) happens
3. your listener gets a reference to the `select` and changes a property on it
4. the browser/thing responsible for rendering DOM is designed in such a way that changing that `disabled` property on `select`s does what one expects

Also `this.row.querySelector('.workProject') !== this.nodes.workProject`.

Comment: Isn't `this.row.querySelector('.workProject')` a reference to the object's `row` property?(which is a virtual DOM element). It is not referencing the dom itself as `document.querySelector()` would do.

Comment: Right, but "virtual DOM" is still DOM like your main document DOM, nothing special about it in that way. And the moment you import it in your "main" DOM it's part of it.

Comment: So we could say that adding a virtual DOM element to the "main" DOM creates a one-way data binding relation?

Comment: No. Has nothing to do with data binding. Data binding is something UI framework people named a feature, there is no such thing defined by DOM/browsers. What you have here is basic DOM manipulation and events with the added complexity of "virtual DOM" which in your case is only an easy way to generate DOM fragments. But yes, no one is stoping you from calling it anything :)

Comment: So to be more technical, the "main" DOM element somehow points to my object's `row` property and is aware of any changes it gets, to be updated right?

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around this "Virtual DOM" concept. When something changes, does the whole row render again or just the changed element? Sorry for making so many questions, just trying to learn haha. And thanks for your help!

Comment: No. Again, there is no "data binding" happening here. You can ignore the whole virtual DOM par too. All that is happening is what I described in those four steps. `this.row` is a reference to a DOM Node. `querySelector` on it will match other DOM Nodes inside of it.